# Quanteda: Error in validObject(.Object): invalid class "dfm" object: superclass "Mnumeric" not defined in the environment of the object's class

Tags: text-mining, quanteda

I am running the following codes to change my tokens to dfm objects. It was smoothly working in the past. I haven't changed the version of my quanteda(version 2.0.1). Now I have an error which I can't solve at the moment.

***Error in validObject(.Object): invalid class "dfm" object: superclass "Mnumeric" not defined in the environment of the object's class***

```
dfmat_train <- dfm(traintokens)
dfmat_test <- dfm(testtokens)

head(dfmat_train,2)

head(dfmat_test,2)
```

[image]

Comment: This is impossible to reproduce without more information, but I strongly suspect it is because your version of quanteda is about 2 years old, and probably also your version of the Matrix package. Update everything and it should work.

Comment: Thanks. It worked after reinstalling the latest version of quanteda.

Comment: We should close this question since it’s a user installation problem, not a SO question.

Comment: @Ken, please, a last question before closing:  
I have got the exact same error when using your dataset `data_corpus_LMRD` from your dropbox, that is,  
`load(url("https://www.dropbox.com/s/sjdfmx8ggwfda5o/data_corpus_LMRD.rda?dl=1"))`  
Although it is a .rda file I guessed I could load it in memory and save it as .rds. This was right, but when I read it using readRDS() and I run  
`dfm(tokens(data_corpus_LMRD))`   
I get that error :-S  
Do you have a newer version of data_corpus_LMRD ?  

Best regards,  

-Mariano